# <a> element in <p> messes up in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

The following code causes the outer `<a>` tag to show twice and splits the contents of the `<p>` tag:

```html
  <a href="https://five-pillars-simulator.luisafk.repl.co" target="fivepillarssmiluator" class="card dfc tc mw m40 cb tdn">
    <h2 class="card-title">
      Five Pillars Simulator
    </h2>
    <p class="card-body tj">
      A History Project me and <a href="https://replit.com/@gabrielo4">Gabe</a> made for a school History project.
    </p>
  </a>
```

It seems the problem is the `<a>` tag inside the `<p>` because if I remove it it shows correctly.

Current behaviour:
[image]

Expected behaviour (or without the second `<a>`):
[image]

The elements in Chrome DevTools with the messed up behaviour:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have nested `<a>` tags.

You inner `<a>` tag links to the same target, so there is no reason to add an extra `<a>` tag.

If you want to style them differently consider using for instance a `<span>` for the inner "link"

Comment: Then how can I achieve what I'm trying to do? I have the main div thing which should take you to the project, but I also want to link to my friend's profile. Do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: @LuisAFK Without seeing the rest of the project is difficult to say. I would suggest to add two "link button" to the card. One for the project (instead of linking the whole card), one for the profile